# Rational infinite continued fractions

Tags: calculus, number-theory, analysis, continued-fractions

According to the Wikipedia article on continued fractions, the numerical value of any infinite continued fraction is irrational: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction?wprov=sfla1

This, however, does not agree with the fact that
$$1=\frac{3}{2+\frac{3}{2+\frac{3}{2+\ddots}}}$$
Could anyone explain what am I missing?

Comment: Also in the wikipedia article "It is generally assumed that the numerator of all of the fractions is 1. If arbitrary values and/or functions are used in place of one or more of the numerators or the integers in the denominators, the resulting expression is a generalized continued fraction." The statement doesn't hold for generalized continuted fractions.

Comment: When citing a theorem, it may be useful to make sure of the definitions used there.

Comment: In the terminology I learned, every infinite **simple** continued fraction is irrational; "simple" meaning that the numerators are ones.